# destroy Page in window phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am doing a game on windows phone but I have trouble following. When moving from page 1 to page 2, I want to destroy Page 1 and when I hit the back button, the page 1 is reset. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "destroyed" and "reset"? Have you looked at the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` methods?

Comment: I think it is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Set `NavigationCacheMode` property in page 1 in its constructor:

```
public Page1()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
}
```

See the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: sorry occurred error!    Error 1 Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Controls.Page.NavigationCacheMode' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Then you should remove the Page1 from the navigation Backtrace and handle back press event navigating to a new Page1